# Grid $2\times3$ colored with four colours

Tags: combinatorics

I  have  a $2\times3$ grid  which   is  colored  with   four colours.  How  many   colourings  do there   exists  such that   every two  adjacent squares have  different   colours?  I  don't  know   how  to   start.

Comment: Start by trying to solve similar problems for smaller grids and fewer colors.

Comment: @MJD   What  is  the  basic  idea?

Comment: This idea should work but not in general: Top middle cell has 4 choices, neighbors have 3 choices, then take cases for the last two cells.

Answer (score 3):

Color the grid by columns (top and bottom cells) going from left to right:

You have  $4\cdot 3=12$ ways to color the $1$st column. Now given that you've made your choice of colors for the $1$st column, the  number of ways to color the $2$nd column will drop down from $12$ to $7$. The same happens for the 3rd column, once you've colored the $2$nd one . So the total number is
$$12\cdot 7 \cdot 7=588.$$

Comment: WHy 7?  They  are 6?

Comment: Let A, B,C, D be the four colors. Suppose the $1$st column is (A,B)  (A on the top, and B on the bottom).  Can you list the possibilities for the $2$nd column?

Comment: Sorry,  you  have  right!